# help with facebook and twitter share buttons

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, wordpress, twitter

im trying to create something similar to this, which is going to show up on each post that I put on my wordpress site. ideally I want it so i can try it out on normal HTML then transfer it to wordpress if possible.

[image]

can some one advice me on what the best way of doing this would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a share-this plugin u can download this lets you set custom settings for social websites.

http://help.sharethis.com/integration/wordpress

Answer (score 2):

wordpress has plugins to achive this.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fblikebutton/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-twitter-retweet-button/screenshots/

These are developer's api page from facebook and twitter you can refer them too,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button